Refresh click provided and windows & UX
I am sure you all must be using windows from really long time. If so there is one hobby that users have developed.
The 'Refresh'

Though windows has undergone many iterations of design language one thing is kept universal and unchanged even when we are at Windows 11.
When I do user interviews for my ongoing Design project, I see people use this option more often without realizing why they do it and they tell 'just like that'.
Is this particularly maintained from so long as a part of user experience that is accepted by default from the user?
Want to know your perspectives.

I think this is a legacy option from Windows 95. It has also to do with the File Explorer which provides these options for every folder - and the desktop is just a special folder to be displayed by the Explorer.
The legacy usage was once that files could be renamed but stayed in place where they were. Upon "Refresh" the files got resorted and the renamed file was shown at the "right" position.
This was changed, I think it was either in Win7 or 10, when renaming immediately caused a refresh to show the sorted files list. This made the "Refresh" obsolete actually, but was not removed.
The immediate refresh made things worse: if you try to rename a bunch of files close together now, it makes it necessary to jump "back" to the old position after each rename in order to select the next file to rename.
It was some kind of quick hack. The "refresh on change" function was there for a long time but it wasn't activated. Then somebody at MS decided to "modernize" Explorer's behavior and axed usability for it.

Thank you for sharing these factoids.
